# Building Nixos config where I merge two attribute sets with mkMerge results in error of "The option `imports' does not exist. Definition values..."

Tags: nixos, nix

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to have a Nixos configuration defined, that can be

1. Installed (this would be the `configuration-pineapple.nix` file)
2. Installed/run as a VM, by setting some additional config (`vmExtra`), I'm using `nixos-shell` for this which in turn uses `nix-build '<nixpkgs/nixos>' -A vm...`.

`vm-pineapple.nix`:

```
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }: 
let vmExtra = 
  {
    virtualisation = {
      cores = 6;
      memorySize = 8000;
      qemu.guestAgent.enable = true;
      diskSize = 1024*20;
      graphics = false;
    };
  };
in
  lib.mkMerge [
    ((import (./configuration-pineapple.nix)) { config = config; pkgs = pkgs; })
    vmExtra
  ]
```

The above errors with:

```
 nixos-shell /etc/nixos/vm-pineapple.nix
error: The option `imports' does not exist. Definition values:
       - In `/etc/nixos/vm-pineapple.nix':
           [
             /etc/nixos/hardware-configuration.nix
             /etc/nixos/services.nix
             /etc/nixos/desktop-services.nix
             /etc/nixos/services/pgbouncer.nix
           ...
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

**My question:** Why might I be getting this error? And how could I achieve the above objective?

**What I've tried:**

I've tried to make a simple example using `mkMerge` to perhaps better understand whats going wrong. I've created a `x.nix` file with:

```
{}: 
let
  a = { a.example = "hi"; };
  b = { a.example2 = "bye" ; b.example2 = "hello"; };
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in
  { fv = nixpkgs.lib.mkMerge [ a b ]; }
```

And running this via `nix eval --file x.nix fv` results in:

```
{ _type = "merge"; contents = [ { a = { example = "hi"; }; } { a = { example2 = "bye"; }; b = { example2 = "hello"; }; } ]; }
```

Which looks a lot different than what I expected (I didn't expect the wrapping structure). In which case it makes me think that `mkMerge` is not the appropriate function to be using for what I want.

Comment: Where did you find mkMerge? I can not find it in the nixpkgs manual.  Maybe you want the `//` operator instead?